# I need help identifying volunteer vegetable plant from compost

Tags: identification, vegetables

I have a  volunteer vegetable patch. Mostly pumpkin and various tomatoes have grown from cold compost (plus some deadly nightshade). But one plant has come up that I cannot identify. We tend to put pumpkins, tomatoes, capsicum (peppers) and potatoes in the compost.

Photo shows stalk of plant (growing surrounded by pumpkins and tomatoes), a closer shot of leaves and plant from another angle

[image: plants in a compost bin]

Comment: Basil or pepper. Rub the leaf to determine if herbal.

Answer (score 2):

It very much looks like a pepper to me. Leaf shape, leaf color. Plant habit. Everything. If there's a reason you don't think it's a pepper, feel free to let me know!